# safari margin top different than chrome and firefox

Tags: html, css, safari

I currently am using a margin to push page content out from under a fixed header. To match the header's height of 110px, i've given the content a margin of 110px. I've seen safari having issues with margin % but not with a set pixel size. For complicated reasons this needs to be done with a top margin, but safari is ignoring it. It does say when i view the source that there is a margin of 110px, but it's behaving as if there's a margin of ~20px. So:

1. why is this happening?
2. how do i fix it?

**EDIT**

This is built on a bootstrap theme from hell.

Answer (score 0):

I think padding is no option here? have you tried applying box-sizing: border-box to your CSS?

```
html {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

EDIT: have you tried

```
top: 110px;
```

?

EDIT:
Adding a DIV with the height of 110px? Brute force ... ;)
Ten years ago i would have used a transparent 1x1px GIF and set it's height to 110px.

Comment: I should of added that this is built on bootstrap, i believe box-sizing: border -box is already global if I'm not mistaken? Using padding would be an option except when I do that, for some reason they are combined with the margins. This is a horrible site that a client asked us to edit that is made with wordpress and the worst bootstrap based theme ever, and I really just want to stab myself in the eyes. Now that I've vented that out, no, I really think I'm stuck with finding out fixing the existing margin, hacking it with !important didn't even work such as `margin: 0 !important; padding:...`

Comment: ah crap, the problem with that is that margin is still coming in, and on other browsers there will be a 220px gap with the margin and the div. Is there a way to just target the css for just safari? The downside is chrome works, so i can't target just webkit. If so, padding should work I would think. It does work already, it just applies to the other browsers, making the same 220px gap for them.

Comment: Delete the margin you used before(?). Don't need it anymore with the brute force method ... all other browsers understand the brute force language, too.

Comment: I've got to find it, it's not in the stylesheet, nor inline for the html for that page, and i can't think of where else they put it. Looks like finding it will be my only hope :(

Comment: ive discovered the body is coming below the fixed header on all browsers besides safari for some reason. none of the browsers are showing a margin or position on the body tag though...

Comment: I discovered the issue, turns out there was a `top: 110px;` set on the body, that was ignored on safari. if you want to set that as an answer ill accept it, dunno if this question will help anyone else, but you deserve the credit for working with me on this.

Comment: ah okay, i'm glad you found the problem, sometimes CSS/HTML can make a man nuts :) .

Comment: Thanks, and yeah, especially when it is someone else's work you are editing and there is zero organization or logic to it! If you want to make your answer something like look for that spacing being added on another element ill accept it as an answer and give you the credit.